# Deletion of a record from a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I'm making a program that will delete a particular record having a particular id which the user will enter. The record is deleted from an existing csv file called Database.csv and a temp file called temp.csv is created to help this process. The code is compiled and runs but when I enter the id which I want to delete the console shows a dialog box saying error but doesn't detail the error. What error it could might be and how to resolve it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.*;  

public class delete {
    public static Scanner x;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "Database.csv";
        System.out.print("Enter the id you want to delete: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String removeTerm = sc.nextLine();
        removeRecord(filepath,removeTerm);

    }

    public static void removeRecord(String filepath, String removeTerm)
{
    String tempFile = "temp.csv";
    File oldFile = new File(filepath);
    File newFile = new File(tempFile);
  String id=""; String fn=""; String ln=""; String sl=""; String lc="";
  try{ 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(bw);
    x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
    x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
    while(x.hasNext())
    {
        id = x.next();
        fn = x.next();
        ln = x.next();
        sl = x.next();
        lc = x.next();
        if(!id.equals(removeTerm))
        {
                pw.println(id + "," + fn + "," + ln + "," + sl + "," + lc);

        }
    }
    x.close();
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    oldFile.delete();
    File dump = new  File(filepath);
    newFile.renameTo(dump);
  }


    catch(Exception e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Print the exception message in the catch block, and you can see what is your problem.

Comment: @rockfarkas already have the exception message there. Doesn't tell anything about the error.

Comment: .txt file works with this code but .cvs is giving an error. In case of .cvs a temp.cvs is made and not deleted which also means the data isn't written to the Database.cvs that is the main file

Comment: Creating a message box that says "error" is not the same as simply doing **the usual** (wink wink, nudge nudge) "e.printStackTrace();" which has all the information you could need. Which we translate for you, if you give it to us.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what error it might be if you print the exception:

- Print the stack trace to `System.err`:

  ```
  } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }
  ```
- Use JOptionPane, and print the exception to there:

  ```
  } catch (Exception e) {

      String message = "Message: " + e.getMessage()
              + "\nStackTrace: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace());
      String title = e.getClass().getName();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  ```

I think you can resolve it after you know your problem.